# How to extend external Typescript library interface when the name contains special characters?

Tags: typescript, strapi

I know that this is a question that exists already, but I could not find it with special characters namespaces containing `@` `/`.

Use case:

I want to extend `import { Strapi } from '@strapi/strapi';` the `Strapi` interface from @strapi/strapi.
It is missing `webhookStore` and other properties which I want to add.

**First approach**

I created `extentions.d.ts` with the following content

```
declare global {
    namespace '@strapi/strapi' {
        interface Strapi {
            webhookStore: {
                c: any;
            };
        }
    }
}
```

and it does not work. Typescript complains `TS1003: Identifier expected.` for '@strapi/strapi'

[image]

I have extended successfully interfaces that had single names like "Stripe" etc but in this case I don't know how to implement that.

I cannot use @strapi/strapi without `'` wrapping as it will be compilation error.

**Second approach - module augmentation/merging**

I also tried the `module augmentation` that is propsed here as well, but did not work.

```
type WebhookStore = {
    findWebhooks: () => void;
};

declare module '@strapi/strapi' {
    interface Strapi {
        webhookStore: WebhookStore;
    }
}
```

This is redeclaring the Strapi interface and both the editor PhpStorm recognises only webhookStore as the only property! (losing info about the other exported ones by the lib itself). Also fails to compile as ts compiler again recognises only webhookStore. It is redeclaring and no merge happens

Results in many errors like this during `yarn build` which is linting and compiling

```
5 import { factories } from '@strapi/strapi';
           ~~~~~~~~~
src/api/tag/routes/tag.ts:5:10 - error TS2305: Module '"@strapi/strapi"' has no exported member 'factories'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking to do is called, declaration merging/ module augmentation. Here's how you [augment a module](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) -

```ts
import API from "@strapi/strapi";

declare module "@strapi/strapi/lib/types/core/index" {
    interface Strapi {
        webhookStore: { c: any }
    }
}

declare global {
  namespace Strapi {
    export type Webhook = { c: any };
  }
}

const store = API({}).webhookStore
 //   ^? const store: { c: any; }

let a: Strapi.Webhook
//  ^? let a: Strapi.Webhook
```

Here's a [link to the playground](https://tsplay.dev/Nda0ym);

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. I have tried this already and does not work. I can see the `webhookStore` property but I cannot see the original declarations exporeted by Strapi interface when I do this... So it is not merging but just redeclaring..

Comment: Also phpstorm/intellij cannot find the previous properties https://ibb.co/2nXHhXS

Comment: What's the version of library you're using? It's working in the playground that I provided a link for, and that's the latest version.

Comment: I am using `"@strapi/strapi": "4.12.0",`

Comment: Alright, I just checked the library itself. Through this declaration merging, it is adding it to the main class and it's available on the global `strapi` namespace object. Try and see if an IDE restart does the trick. Also, all the other properties are visible, not just `webhookStore`.

Comment: The problem is also with the linter and tsc compiler not only with the editor. They think that the original properties don't exist anymore `5 import { factories } from '@strapi/strapi';
           ~~~~~~~~~
src/api/tag/routes/tag.ts:5:10 - error TS2305: Module '"@strapi/strapi"' has no exported member 'factories'.
` They recognise only the re-declared properties

Comment: Try this once? I've updated my answer.

Comment: I tested and works great. It does compile, lint + recognised by the editor. This is my code https://ibb.co/252mx7x. I want also to add some types inside the Strapi namespace like `Webhook` etc. That is the next step because currently I export them from my own file

Comment: Updated my answer to reflect the namespace change.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to have a `namespace` named `@strapi/strapi`, as that is neither a valid TypeScript identifier nor a valid ECMAScript identifier.

`namespace`s are used to represent global ECMAScript objects and as such need to be valid TypeScript / ECMAScript identifiers.

Comment: thanks for the reply... This is very weird and a bad design of typescript I would say not offering a solution for such a use case. I don't want to use `// @ts-ignore` every time I access properties `that do exist` but are not offered in the library ts types. `    // @ts-ignore const webhooks = strapi.webhookStore.findWebhooks();`

Comment: Are you sure there is no workaround to extend it with something else ? I am not looking for a solution limited to `namespaces` only. It can be anything that allows me to use the same import from the external library with it existing properties + new extra ones I add by extending

Comment: I don't understand. `@strapi/strapi` is not a legal identifier in ECMAScript either, so it is impossible to have an object with this name.

Comment: It is allowed to be used in import statement. This is valid and works fine `import { Strapi } from '@strapi/strapi';` @strapi/strapi is the package name in package.json of Strapi lib `"name": "@strapi/strapi",`

Comment: This is the module specifier. The module specifier is not an ECMAScript object, therefore, it cannot be typed using a TypeScript namespace. TypeScript namespaces are for ECMAScript objects, not things which aren't objects.